# Javascript async function not working

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have following example:

```
var first=setInterval(function() {  
var t=new Date();  
console.log("Started: ",t);  
sleep(function(){  
    var t=new Date();  
    console.log("Finished: ",t);  
});  
},500);  

function sleep(callback){  
for (var i=0;i<10000000000;i++){  
     //waiting
  }  
  callback();  
 }
```

IMHO sleep should execute asynchronously, but it doesnt, output:

```
Started:  Mon Mar 04 2013 12:31:10 GMT+0200 (EET)  
Finished:  Mon Mar 04 2013 12:31:23 GMT+0200 (EET)  
Started:  Mon Mar 04 2013 12:31:24 GMT+0200 (EET)  
Finished:  Mon Mar 04 2013 12:31:36 GMT+0200 (EET)  
Started:  Mon Mar 04 2013 12:31:36 GMT+0200 (EET)
```

Comment: *"IMHO sleep should execute asynchronously"* Why? You've done nothing to make it asynchronous. (That is, within the `setInterval` callback.)

Comment: You're mistaken about how JavaScript works with threading.  All code is executed on a single thread, callbacks from asynchronous operations must wait for the thread to become idle before they can be executed themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` won't trigger the next call to the callback while the previous call to the callback is still running. Since your `sleep` function is in no way asynchronous, it holds up subsequent `setInterval` callbacks.

In browsers, barring the use of [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/), all JavaScript code is executed on a *single thread*. It looks like your code is trying to set up a situation where `sleep` will be running, and then a subsequent callback from `setInterval` will be fired and start a second thread running `sleep`. That doesn't happen (see the above).

You *can* use web workers to do something like that, though, if you have long-running operations you want running off the main JavaScript thread (on [browsers that support them](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers)).